# How to run multiple VS Code instances to use different identities for interacting with a remote git repository while working with Remote Containers?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, ssh-agent

Sorry for a long post

I have a VS Code Remote Development setup using containers. I have multiple user accounts for the same git server. I am using key-based authentication to interact with git-server. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in my host machine and Debian Buster in containers.

```
Git Server - git.server.com
Git urls 
 - git@git.server.com:repo1.git
 - git@git.server.com:repo2.git

Repo1 is used by User1 account
Repo2 is used by User2 account

ssh-key for User1 - ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_user1
ssh-key for User2 - ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_user2
```

I have created an ssh config in ~/.ssh/config

```
Host user1.git.server.com
    HostName git.server.com
    User git
    IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_user1
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host user2.git.server.com
    HostName git.server.com
    User git
    IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_user2
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

From a terminal in host machine I can authenticate to server

as user1:

```
ssh git@user1.git.server.com
```

as user2:

```
ssh git@user2.git.server.com
```

I can launch multiple vs code instances and inside the vs code terminal (without opening the folder in remote container), I can use the above commands to authenticate.

Things get interesting once we use "Reopen in Containers".
I don't have the .ssh/config folder mounted inside containers so the above commands fail to execute by giving error:

```
Could not resolve hostname user1.git.server.com: Name or service not known
or
Could not resolve hostname user2.git.server.com: Name or service not known
```

I don't want to mount my `./ssh` folder to containers for obvious reasons. Also `mount=type=ssh` is also not possible as this is not building a container but working with container as a dev environment.

Next thing I notice is that ssh-agent forwarding is working.

```
ssh-add -l
```

If I execute the above command in terminal in host, terminal in vs code (when folder is opened locally) and terminal in vs code (when folder is opened in remote container) all returns same output (the fingerprint for keys of identities for user1 and user2).

So I start a new ssh-agent in host terminal before launching the code.

```
~/repo1$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
~/repo1$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_user1
~/repo1$ code .

and in another terminal
~/repo2$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
~/repo2$ ssh-add ~/id_ed25519_user2
~/repo2$ code .
```

In respective host terminal and vs code terminal (without opening folder in remote container) I get the desired result. I can use:

```
ssh git@git.server.com
```

So I don't need a ssh-config file anymore.
But this does not work when the folder is opened in Remote Container. VS Code only connects to the first ssh-agent started. That is (in this case) the repo1 opened in VS Code Remote Container works perfectly with all git support but repo2 opened in VS Code Remote Container does not work.

How can I direct VS Code to use which ssh-agent to forward to container when switching to remote container?

### Workaround

The workaround which I am using currently is use the default ssh-agent (Ubuntu starts an ssh-agent at the time of logging in). This agent already contains both the identities. Verify by running

```
ssh-add -l
```

Launch multiple vs code instances as usual and switch to Remote Container.
When I want to perform a git operation I do the following in host terminal:

```
For repo1 (user1) operations
$ ssh-add -D
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_user1

For repo2 (user2) operations
$ ssh-add -D
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_user2
```

Is there any other suggested way? Is there any settings that can be added to devcontainer.json to achieve the proper forwarding of ssh-agent?

Thank you for your patience.